# Running the contents of a file through a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

very new to coding here
I'm trying to create a program that will run through two files containing data sets and look for over laps, and print out that range of over laps.
the 2 files I was given have a name start, stop
for example

in file 1:

```
distance 567 890
distance 345 678
distance 123 347
distancex 56 201
```

in file 2

```
distance 456 678
distance 345 678
distance 1000 2000
distancex 1056 2030
```

so for the two files, i want test if there is overlab between the numbers.

```
file1=open('filea.file', 'r')

file2=open('fileb.file', 'r')

lst=[]

for item in file1:
    item = item.split()
    column1 = item[0]
    start1 = item[1]
    stop1 = item[2]
    lst.append(item)
    print item

for item in file2:
    item = item.split()
    column2 = item[0]
    start2 = item[1]
    stop2 = item[2]
    lst.append(item)
    print item



def compare(file1, file2):
    for items in lst:
        if (column1==column2) and (start1>start2) and (stop2>start1) and (stop1>stop2):
            print start1 + "," + stop2
        elif (column1==column2) and (stop2>start1): 
            print "none"
        elif (column1==column2) and (stop1>start2):
            print "none"
        elif (column1==column2) and (start2>start1) and (stop1>start2) and (stop2>stop1):
            print start2 + ","+ stop1
        elif (column1==column2) and (start1>=start2) and (stop2>=stop1):
            print start1 + "," + stop1
        elif (column1==column2) and (start2>=start1) and (stop1>=stop2):
            print start2 + "," + stop2
```

when i run this i just get a read out of the files and nothing with the if statements

what am i missing??

Comment: You should start with the Python tutorial first before doing more complicated things: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: define overlap more clearly, how about a desired output

Comment: by overlap I mean, in the lists: there is a start and stop number given. i want to compare the overlap of those start and stops between file 1 and two. Like imagine, runner 1 ran from the  567 mile mark to  the 890 mile mark. runner 2 ran from the 456 mile mark to the  678 mile mark. I want the computer to spit out that the overlap that these runners ran was from the 579 mile mark to the 678 mile mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of all, you get only the file readout because you never call your function.

After that, note that

1. Your function never uses the files you try to pass it
2. You can't read more from the files; your main program already read everything
3. You haven't properly put your triples into `lst` -- your loops take only the first triple from each input line.

I recommend that you work gradually -- use incremental programming.  Write a few lines, make sure that you have the progress you expect, and *then* go on to the next step.  As this stands, you wrote over 30 lines of active code, but your program fails to do what you want (I think) in the first few lines.